# Is there a way to "overlay" two (pandas) dataframes at a specific position?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my pseudo code

```
source

   a  b  c  d  e
0  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  x  x  x
3  x  x  x  x  x
4  x  x  x  x  x
5  x  x  x  x  x
```

And then I have a lookup dataframe

```
lookup

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```

Is there any function that would behave something like this - `pd.source.overlay(lookup[2,c])` -     producing an "overlay" at a specific position?

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  1  2  3
3  x  x  x  x  x
4  x  x  x  x  x
5  x  x  x  x  x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [898]: df.iloc[2, -3:] = lu.values

In [899]: df
Out[899]: 
   a  b  c  d  e
0  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  1  2  3
3  x  x  x  x  x
4  x  x  x  x  x
5  x  x  x  x  x
```

Answer (score 0):

First we ge the index , then assign the value

```
df.values[2,2:]=lu.values
df
   a  b  c  d  e
0  x  x  x  x  x
1  x  x  x  x  x
2  x  x  1  2  3
3  x  x  x  x  x
4  x  x  x  x  x
5  x  x  x  x  x

col='c'

df.values[2,df.columns.get_indexer([col])[0]:]=lu.values
```

Comment: Just like that? For a newbie like me, that's beautiful

Comment: @Maxcot since you assign the value not match the index and columns ,so we need do the values, remove the index impact